# Есть ли русский вариант выражения "два сна в одной постели"?

Tags: фразеология

Существует ли русский вариант поговорки  "два сна в одной постели"?

Answer (score 1):

Это не поговорка, тянет максимум на эвфемизм. Означает, как и следует из прямого перевода, "спать в одной постели".

Может, помимо прочего, использоваться для обозначения двуместного гостиничного номера с общей кроватью, в частности - для молодоженов, но в последнем случае более употребительно "Honeymoon suit".

==

опечатка в слове "эвфемизм" - спасибо, исправил

Comment: опечатка в слове "эвфемизм"